# Scroll Magic scrollmagic-pin-spacer not resizing on window resize

Tags: javascript, frontend, scrollmagic

I'm working on a website that is built using CRA (Create React App ), which I combined with ScrollMagic and GSAP.

The API is mainly used in the home page where I pin the root div so that nothing moves on a scroll apart from the animation in the middle.

I've noticed that ScrollMagic will use pixel-based units to fix the padding and the width of the pinned element, which I believe is the problem with my page. Indeed when you resize the page from the bottom right all the content gets cut off.

I'm sure there are some fixes with using javascript on window resize, but I truly don't know where to start, as I have experience with JS but not to this extends of manipulation.

Can anyone help me?